# Using a smart pointer to manage memory allocated within function

Tags: c++, arrays, smart-pointers

**Background**

If I had a function `foo` as follows

```
void foo(std::vector<int>& values)
{
    values = std::vector<int>(10, 1);
}
```

Then I could call it as

```
std::vector<int> values;
foo(values);
```

Notice that the initial `vector` is empty, then it is populated within the function `foo`.

I often come across interfaces that I cannot change (i.e. 3rd party), that have the same intention as above, but using raw arrays, for example

```
void foo(int*& values)
{
    values = new int[10];
    std::fill_n(values, 10, 1);
}
```

My problem with these is that now I am responsible for managing that memory, e.g.

```
int* values;
foo(values);
delete[] values;
```

**Question**

Is there any way I can use smart pointers to manage this memory for me? I would like to do something like

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> values;
foo(values.get());
```

but `get` returns a pointer that is an r-value, so I cannot pass it by non-const reference.

Comment: I don't know if this is legal but it does compile: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/860ae38fd2cdb4a2

Answer (score 2):

1. Create empty unique_ptr.
2. Create pointer.
3. Pass pointer to function.
4. Reset unique_ptr to that pointer.

Like that:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> values;
int* values_ptr;
foo(values_ptr);
values.reset(values_ptr);
```

Or:

```
int* values_ptr;
foo(values_ptr);
std::unique_ptr<int[]> values(values_ptr);
```

Comment: In fact make_unique builds the thing itself, you can't give it a pointer, or can you?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: you cannot.
But i believe there is a way to simplify you life. Since you always do the same thing, you simply have to write a function that does it for you and call that function when you need. Since i suppose you want to use the returned value written in memory before releasing it, i make my function return it.

```
template <typename T, typename Function>
std::unique_ptr<T[]> call(Function f) {
  T * value;
  f(value);
  return { value };
}

// then to use it
auto value = call<int>(foo);
```

Would that suit you?

The function could be improved to detect the difference for pointers to one object or to an array if you need it, and it could probably also be improved to detect automatically the needed parameter type so that you do not have to type it.